# Expect Continue Inconsistencies on Different Environments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, couchbase

I have some troubles with the header `Expect 100-Continue` on a DELETE method inside a .NET 4.5 application. The client in provides also a small content body inside the call.

1. The [official microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepoint.expect100continue?view=netframework-4.8) seems to imply that this header is passed by default only in PUT and POST calls with a non-empty content, but it does not say nothing about DELETE. Does anyone know if this configuration also applies to DELETE?
2. I'm experiencing different behaviour on different environment of my web application in particular I have some environments in which the header is never passed (even in PUT and POST) without any clue about it being deactivated.

In order to interact with this option I know only four ways:

- Via ServicePointManager through

  ```cs
   System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
  ```
- Editing client options

  ```cs
      var c = new HttpClient();
      c.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
  ```
- Adding or removing it manually on `HttpWebRequest` with  `AddHeader/Remove`
- Using the following property on `Web.Config`

```xml
    <system.net>
       <settings> 
           <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false"/>  
       </settings> 
    </system.net>
```

Unfortunately none of these seems to be my case. Are there any other ways to mess with this option?

Answer (score 1):

Just managed to find out the solution for this issue. I found out that some of my environment use the **couchbase client** to handle distributed cache, differently from IIS couchbase internally sets `Expect100Continue` to `true` but it does that in the following way.

```cs
namespace Couchbase.Configuration.Client
{
  public class ClientConfiguration {

    //...

      public ClientConfiguration()
      { 
        //...
        this.Expect100Continue = false;
      }
    //--
    public bool Expect100Continue
    {
      get
      {
        return ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue;
      }
      set
      {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = value;
      }
    }

  }

}
```

they use change this property using the static `ServicePointManager` method and this means that every following instantiated client will change their behaviour.

My version of Couchbase Client is `2.1.4.0`